# Why local-update-policy for the near cache can be configured only for jcache client?

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, hazelcast, jcache

I am planning to use the Hazelcast as a hibernate second-level cache provider in client-server configuration. There are two options for this. One via hibernate-jcache dependency and the other via hazelcast-hibernate53. hibernate-jcache uses Cache and hazelcast-hibernate53 uses Map.

I am also using the near cache on the clients. For now, I have chosen to go with jcache because it has the ability to configure CACHE_ON_UPDATE for local-update-policy. So I was wondering why this setting could not be configured for IMap clients?

Map has a couple of benefits like more operations available in the management center, and more options for max-size-policy. So I would like to use a map but I don't want to lose the performance benefit on clients that I have with CACHE_ON_UPDATE.

Are there plans in the future to add operation "CLEAR DATA" for the ICache in the management center and adding more options for max-size-policy?

P.S.
What do you thing is the best option here if I have used Ehcache before and time to extract something from the cache is critical for me?